# Next.js App works in development (npm run dev) but fails in production (npm run start) with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, next.js14

I'm working on a Next.js 14 application that uses AWS Amplify Gen 2 for data fetching. Everything works as expected when I run the app in development mode using `npm run dev`. However, when I switch to production mode with `npm run build` followed by `npm run start`, I encounter a TypeError related to AWS Amplify's data fetching.

The specific error is: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')`. This occurs when trying to fetch data from AWS Amplify in my fetchPosts function.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import { generateClient } from 'aws-amplify/data';
import type { Schema } from '@/amplify/data/resource';
// ... other imports ...

interface Post {
    createdAt: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    slug: string;
    titleEn: string;
    titlePt: string;
    titleEs: string;
}

const client = generateClient<Schema>({
    authMode: 'apiKey'
});

async function fetchPosts() {
    console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY); // This logs the API key correctly
    const apiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY;

    if (!apiKey) {
        console.error("API key is missing");
        return [];
    }

    const { data: posts, errors } = await client.models.Posts.list({
        authMode: 'apiKey',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-api-key': apiKey
        }
    });

    return posts as Post[];
}

// ... rest of the code ...
```

The error suggests an issue with accessing the list method, but only in the production build. The environment variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY` is correctly set and logged to the console, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with missing environment variables.

However, the issue persists only in production. What could be causing this discrepancy between development and production environments, and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Run amplify status and amplify push commands to verify that your backend configuration is consistent between local and production.

Comment: When I try to run `amplify status` it gives this error `No Amplify backend project files detected within this folder.`

Comment: Also, when I try to run `amplify pull` it gives this error `Cannot find backend environment in Amplify Console app: myapp`

Comment: if you follow this doc: https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/build-a-backend/data/set-up-data/ you should have an amplify backend folder. cant say for sure because i dont know your folder structure but there is a possibility your amplify backend is not pushed to the server. thats why it is working locally

Comment: I see. I followed the documentation, but there is no backend folder, just these files: `auth  backend.ts  data  package.json  tsconfig.json`

Comment: can you go to your previous directory where the parent folder says amplify and check amplify status alternatively you can also try this doc for deployment https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/start/quickstart/nextjs-pages-router/

Comment: I followed the documentation, but it still gives me this problem `No Amplify backend project files detected within this folder.` Idk, but maybe seeing my repository can help: https://github.com/yohanaff/yohanaf-dev/tree/main

Comment: amplifyconfiguration.json file is in git-ignore did you create the variable in the amplify dashboard?

Comment: Yup. I created an environment variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY` with the value of the api key

Comment: I even committed the amplifyconfiguration.json file, but then it gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')`

Comment: the problem you are having is from this generateClient  as a result of configuration.
To debug try and console the error gotten from const { data: posts, errors } = await client.models. for now try and remove .Post.list the error may point us in the right direction

Comment: I just commented the changes in the develop branch. Idk if that was the change you meant.

Comment: try this first const { data: posts, errors } = await client.models;console.log(errors)

Comment: Then it gives this error: ```Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ModelTypes<{ Posts: { comments: (options?: { authMode?: AuthMode | undefined; authToken?: string | undefined; limit?: number | undefined; nextToken?: string | null | undefined; headers?: CustomHeaders | undefined; } | undefined) => ListReturnValue<...>; ... 11 more ...; owner?: string | undefined; };```

Comment: I typed this `const { data: posts, errors } = await client.models;
console.log(errors)` in the console and gave this error `VM175:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: client is not defined`